# How can I gradually free memory from a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, leveldb

I'm in a situation where I'm constantly hitting my memory limit (I have 20G of RAM). Somehow I managed to get the huge array into memory and carry on my processes. Now the data needs to be saved onto the disk. I need to save it in `leveldb` format.

This is the code snippet responsible for saving the normalized data onto the disk:

```
print 'Outputting training data'

leveldb_file = dir_des + 'svhn_train_leveldb_normalized'
batch_size = size_train

# create the leveldb file
db = leveldb.LevelDB(leveldb_file)
batch = leveldb.WriteBatch()
datum = caffe_pb2.Datum()

for i in range(size_train):
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print i

    # save in datum
    datum = caffe.io.array_to_datum(data_train[i], label_train[i])
    keystr = '{:0>5d}'.format(i)
    batch.Put( keystr, datum.SerializeToString() )

    # write batch
    if(i + 1) % batch_size == 0:
        db.Write(batch, sync=True)
        batch = leveldb.WriteBatch()
        print (i + 1)

# write last batch
if (i+1) % batch_size != 0:
    db.Write(batch, sync=True)
    print 'last batch'
    print (i + 1)
```

Now, my problem is, I hit my limit pretty much at the very end (495k out of 604k items that need to be saved to the disk) when saving to the disk.

To get around this issue, I thought after writing each batch, I release the corresponding memory from the numpy array (data_train) since it seems leveldb writes the data in a transaction manner, and until all the data are written, they are not flushed to the disk!

My second thought is to somehow, make the write non-transactional, and when each batch is written using `the db.Write`, it actually saves the content to the disk.

I don't know if any of these ideas are applicable.

Comment: What's the size of batch_size? If it's entire dataset then reduce it to say 100000.

Comment: wow! Thanks alot! that was the main culprit of me hitting bad_alloc error at the time of writting! 
Thanks alot man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reducing `batch_size` to something smaller than the entire dataset, for example, `100000`.

<sub>Converted to Community Wiki from @ren 's comment</sub>